# Is there graceful degradation in symmetric multi-processing (SMP) systems?

Tags: cpu, multi-processor, smp

Since graceful degradation is a fault-tolerant feature, is it true that in a multi-processor systems with symmetric multi-processing, there will be no graceful degradation?

**Update:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system

Comment: can you link to an article describing what you mean by "graceful degradation"?

Comment: Of course. 

there is one in dutch so I'll just give the wikipedia link.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Sun old enterprise SMP machines had graceful degradation, but most of cheap Intel and AMD systems doesn't

Comment: The minimal requirement to fault-tolerance is CPU hotplug.